# How to check if all duplicates in an array are grouped

Tags: java, arrays, list, duplicates, grouping

I want to check if all similar integers in an array or list are grouped.
`{2, 2, 5, 5, 5, 1, 7, 7, 5, 7}` should give `false`. While `{2, 2, 5, 5, 5, 1, 7, 7, 7}` should give `true`. This is what I have so far and it prints `true` when it should be `false`:

```
public class testing1 {

  public static void main(String[] args){
    int [] x = {2, 2, 5, 5, 5, 1, 7, 7, 5, 7};
    System.out.println(isGrouped(x));

  }

  public static boolean isGrouped(int[] x){
    for(int i = 0; i < x.length; i++){
      for(int j = i + 1; j < x.length; j++){
        if(x[i] == x[j]) 
          return true;
      }
    }
    return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: what does your code print

Comment: you need to keep an set of numbers checked already

Comment: @NavneetKrishna it prints true when it should be false

Comment: Did you guys even read his question? Its pretty clear, comon.

Comment: Just find the number of occurrences of each duplicate values. Then you have to check inside the loop in such a way that all that occurrences are grouped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your answer, as mentioned in other answers does not take care of all the cases and hence will not work for a number of cases. Also, you don't need 2 loops here. You could store the already seen elements in a hash and for every element in the list if it appears for the first time or not. If it's not appearing for the first time and if the previous element is not the same as this, then it should be false.

Here is the code:

```
public class testing1 {

  public static void main(String[] args){
    int [] x = {2, 2, 5, 5, 5, 1, 7, 7, 5, 7};
    System.out.println(isGrouped(x));
  }

  public static boolean isGrouped(int[] x){

      int prev = x[0] ;

    Hashtable<Integer, Integer> hashtable = 
              new Hashtable<Integer, Integer>();
    hashtable.put(x[0], 0);
    for (int i = 1 ; i < x.length ; i ++)
    {
        if (hashtable.get(x[i]) != null && prev == x[i]){
            hashtable.put(x[i], hashtable.get(x[i]) + 1);
        }

        else if (hashtable.get(x[i]) != null && prev != x[i]){
            return false;
        }

        else{
            hashtable.put(x[i], 0);
        }
        prev = x[i];
    }
    return true ;
    }

}
```

This also stores the count of the number of occurrences of each element.
Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 2):

You currently are getting incorrect output since

```
for(int i = 0; i < x.length; i++){
  for(int j = i + 1; j < x.length; j++){
    if(x[i] == x[j]) 
      return true;
  }
}
```

returns `true` as soon it find a consecutive occurrence of any number( in your case 2,2). Note that this exits the loop and control reaches the print statement calling your `isGrouped` method where it would print `true`.

Actually, in short, ***you do not traverse the complete list in this case unless all the numbers are different in the list.***

To do that otherwise, you should maintain a list of traversed elements or a flag set to true for every element traversed once. Also, you won't need nested loops there.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a hint at how to implement the algorithm.

1. You need a loop going though all elements/indices of the array
2. For every element, you have to test if the element is allowed to be present at this index.

So, when is an element allowed to be there?

1. If it's the first element of the array, it's allowed to be there
2. If it's equal to the previous element, it's allowed to be there
3. If it's different from the previous element, and it's the first time this value is met in the array, it's allowed to be there
4. otherwise, it's not allowed to be there.

Answer (score 1):

Your code doesn't work because as soon as it finds two adjacent values that are equal, it returns true.

One solution would be:

- Remove **consecutive** duplicates from the input array
- Remove **all** duplicates from the input array (convert to set and then to array again)
- Compare results - if the two are equal, you return true, false otherwise

---

Creating new array without consecutive duplicates:

```
for (int i = 1; i < x.length; i++) {
    if (x[i-1] != x[i]) {
        newArr.add(x[i]);
    }
}
```

Now you remove all duplicates:

```
Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<>();
for (int i = 0; i < x.length; i++){
    set.add(x[i]);
}
// create array from the set
```

and compare the two.